# Mask out values in a raster based on standard deviation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, reclassify, masking

Does anyone know (in Modelbuilder or python) how I can remove any values of a raster that outside of the range of three standard deviations? I have a lot of rasters so it would be quicker than manually making a mask from reclassifying and then using SetNull.